# PHP: Invoking Javascript Command

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a plugin called [Reveal](http://www.zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin/), and trying to fire it based on whether a variable is present in the URL (i.e. www.mysite.com?status=new). I have tested the GET status code (works fine, echoed it) and also set up reveal to work when a button is pressed. Both work flawlessly. However, the goal is to fire the event if the status == new. This is my code:

```
<?
if($status == 'new'){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">$(\'#myModal\').reveal();
</script>';
}
?>
```

Doesn't work :/ Any help? I've tried many combinations with this and nothing seems to be working. My code is placed near the bottom of the page (in the body section), not sure if that matters..

EDIT: Also tried this (didn't work):

```
<?
if($status == 'new'){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
          e.preventDefault();
      $(\'#myModal\').reveal();
     });
</script>';
}
?>
```

Zach

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Does the JS get output? Is `status` "new"?

Comment: @Pekka: The JS does output, I checked the source. But the actual plugin didn't fire..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo '
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(\'#myModal\').reveal();
});
</script>';
```

as m90 already suggested, probably a good idea to load up the DOM before you execute the script.  And you can place it anywhere, usually I place it in the head though, but it's all good.

Comment: perhaps an onload event than which will fire after the entire page has been loaded.  What browsers are you testing this in?

Comment: Worked perfectly.. What did I do wrong? Check my post I updated - tried waiting for DOM as well but I did something wrong? Thanks though!

Comment: It's the fact that your `e` wasn't defined. See comment below.

Comment: Your welcome, probably a minor syntax error, who knows.  Congrats.

Comment: Ok thanks guys! I guess I assumed it needed the 'e' because it was provided in the demo markup.. but that makes sense. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that this kind of inline JS will be executed immediately by the browser, so it might be that the element you are trying to reveal isn't ready to be revealed yet (therefore nothing happens). Usually you will fix this by calling your scripts on `$(document).ready()`. See [this article](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29) on the jQuery website

Comment: AND make sure that jquery and the reveal plugin is loaded "before" you call any jquery functions. So if your page loads javascript tags at the end (as is the recommended practice) then it will not work!

Comment: Do you get any errors in your JS console? My first guess would be the problem of an undefined `e` in the code you posted. Do you need to prevent default behavior?

Answer (score 0):

just wanted to put here a little bit different approach:

```
// Example URL:
// test.php?status=Message

var $_GET = <?php echo json_encode( $_GET ); ?>;

// alert( $_GET['status'] );
// console.log($_GET);
```